# Endless connect to network

Tags: networking

My laptop just stopped to connect to networks. The wifi is detecting all the wireless networks around, but when I try to connect the connecting animation is just endless. Same when I plug a ethernet cable. I have tried restarting the computer. The output of `ifconfig` is:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:c1:cc:95  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:126475 (126.4 KB)  TX bytes:26218 (26.2 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:c1200000-c1220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:661996 (661.9 KB)  TX bytes:661996 (661.9 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:02:86:d4:92:7f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:251252 (251.2 KB)  TX bytes:38056 (38.0 KB)
```

Thanks in advance for your attention

EDIT: Here is the output of the network diagnostic script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16925252/

Comment: Please restart the network manager (`sudo service restart network-manager`) and try again. If it still doesn't work [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: thanks for those advices. I have restarted the network-manager, same effect. (I had to use `service reboot` instead of `restart`but I suppose it's the same)

I have pasted the code of the network diagnostic script here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/16925252/

Comment: Oops, that command should have been `sudo service network-manager restart`. Can you try that again please? Anyway, so far your wireless adapter associates with a network but it doesn't receive an IP address or routing information; same for the wired connection. I don't know how to investigate that any further aside from restarting the network manager or possibly restarting the whole machine just to be safe.